# Django Custom User Model

Tags: django

I want to use the user model of django for both authentication and registration of user in my site. I just need to add another field in user model which is a country field. How can I add country to the existing user model ?

Comment: See the [documentation on extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Comment: In addition to what others are saying, it may be dependent on what version of django you are running. Include that information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to define a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

If you want to add one field you can basically extend the existing user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

And set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings module:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.MyUser'
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do that using the OneToOneField found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

1. Create an app (e.g. `python manage.py startapp profile`)
2. Add the app to your settings.py file
3. In your profile/models.py file, add the below example

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   country = models.CharField('country', max_length=120)
```

Comment: Sorry for the way the code looks. I can't get it to format correctly.